# Selenium Python click link on page by text/style

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup

Currently looking at navigating the bet365.com website and i've hit a bit of a standstill. The page I am concerned with has the following URL; https://www.bet365.com/#/AS/B2/.

This page lists all of the horse races on in the current day... I am looking to click on one of those links. The source html can be found below;

```
< div class ="slm-RaceMeeting slm-RaceMeeting_Uk " > 
  < div class ="slm-MeetingHeader " > 
    < div class ="slm-MeetingHeader_LeftContainer " > 
      < div class ="slm-MeetingHeader_RaceName " style="" > Ascot < / div > 
< div class ="slm-RaceMeeting slm-RaceMeeting_Uk " > 
< div class ="slm-RaceMeeting slm-RaceMeeting_Uk " > 
< div class ="slm-RaceMeeting slm-RaceMeeting_Uk " > 
< div class ="slm-RaceMeeting slm-RaceMeeting_Uk " >
```

All race names are wrapped in the class = "slm-RaceMeeting slm-RaceMeeting_Uk " but I can't find any buttons or links that are clickable to navigate to the required meeting (for example navigating to the ascot meeting).

I have tried the following clicks;

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "slm- 
MeetingHeader_RaceName", " " ))]") .click()

browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.slm-MeetingHeader_RaceName').click()
```

...along with numerous other attempts and just can't work this one out! Help would be amazing, very grateful

Comment: I am not able to view the page. But have you try finding whether this is call by javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to click my way through to horse racing and then use xpath as shown below (I gather all results in that section which can be clicked on to different times for Ascot)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.bet365.com/#/AS/B2/')
d.find_element_by_css_selector("a").click()
racing = WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="wn-Classification " and contains(text(),"Horse Racing")]')))
url = d.current_url

while True:
    racing.click()
    if d.current_url !=url:  #might want to add timeout for this. Also, wait clickable doesn't seem to work. But explicit sleep does.
        break
results = d.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="slm-MeetingHeader_RaceName " and contains(text(),"Ascot")]/ancestor::div[@class="slm-RaceMeeting slm-RaceMeeting_Uk "]//*[@class="slm-UkRacingCouponLink_RaceNameTime "]')
results[0].click()
```